# Rounding floats in processing.org

Tags: java, floating-point, processing

Is there any way to round a float to the nearest decimal place in processing?

For example

```
float x = 1.0000001
float y = 1.1000000001

float a = x + y
round(a)

a = 2.10
```

The standard `round()` in processing rounds to the nearest whole number, but I need to have the decimals in place. I can't find a function that does what I'm looking for. I have some floats with over a hundred decimal places so I need to trim them down, if its possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that is more processing-centric:

```
float fixDec(float n, int d) {
  return Float.parseFloat(String.format("%." + d + "f", n));
}
```

and to test it:

```
float x = 1.0000001;
float y = 1.1000000001;
x = fixDec(x, 2);
y = fixDec(y, 2);
float a = x + y;
round(a);
```

this is probably not the most efficient algorithm, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with processing. However, the common way to round to a fixed number of decimal places given a round-to-integer function is:

```
a = round(a * PowerOf10) * InversePowerOf10
```

Thus, for one digit after the decimal point, you might use:

```
a = round(a * 10) * .1
```

There are some caveats and comments:

- This does not work in binary floating point. It is impossible because numbers like .1 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point. If may be close enough, depending on your needs and whether you take appropriate care.
- It may be fine in decimal floating point, but decimal floating point is rare. If processing implements decimal floating point, you may be all set.
- I used multiplication for both operations because multiplication is typically faster than division. However, it may be preferable to use division in certain situations: `a = round(a * PowerOf10) / PowerOf10`. (Notably, in binary floating point, this avoids the extra rounding error in calculating the inverse of PowerOf10.)
- If processing provides extended precision binary floating point, the result may be close enough for your purposes even though it is not exact.
- If you want to format a number for display rather than further calculation, look for string formatting functions instead of numerical rounding functions. Converting a number to a decimal numeral in a string can be done exactly even in binary floating point.

Comment: Thats what nf() a string formater. Sorry for my imprecise Advice.

Answer (score 0):

> Floats are not precise, so avoid adding small values (such as 0.0001)
>   may not always increment because of rounding error. If you want to
>   increment a value in small intervals, use an int, and divide by a
>   float value before using it.

http://processing.org/reference/float.html

```
int i = 10001000;
int j = 11000001;

float a = round((i + j)/pow(10,5));

a /= 100;

println(a);
```

2.1